# Can i make it happen has() in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i'm using vue.js and vuetify.

elements made by parent element exist in my code.

i want to change parent element's class dynamically depending on it's child class, like jQuery `has()` method.

is vue.js has any way to do this?

[jQuery has()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_has.asp)

Comment: quick note that there's nothing wrong about using jquery functions while using Vue. maybe you want a pure JS solution to has()? you may want to add how is this related to Vue.

Comment: use querySelector which directly targets what you want, if it is found it has() it.

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz
Yeah, I know it. actually, it's not my opinion.
My boss not allow to use jquery and vue together in order to avoid code complexity.

Comment: Sounds more your boss wants to introduce complexity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a state if a child property of a child on different ways. (I assume the child class is set based on a certain state).

You could use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) that keep a state over several components. You could [`emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) a state back to you parent component. Or you could use the ref to access the child components properties.

```
<component ref="childcomponent"></markdown>

process: function(){
    // items is defined object inside data() of the child component
    var hasClass= this.$refs.childcomponent.item
}
```